# What is the benefit of using a BindingSource to bind to a DataGridView, rather than a Dataset?

Tags: c#, .net, datagridview

I have a Dataset, which I've filled from a DataAdapter.

Now, I'd like to bind a DataGridView to my DataSet.

I can do the following:

```
dgvCustomers.AutoGenerateColumns = true;
dgvCustomers.DataSource = ds;
dgvCustomers.DataMember = "Table";
```

Or I can do this instead:

```
dgvCustomers.DataSource = new BindingSource(ds, "Table");
```

Is there any reason why one of these would be preferred to the other? My experiments seem to suggest that they both work fine. Thanks!

Comment: you could just use `dgvCustomers.DataSource = ds.Table[0];` and you would not have to rely on the `DataMember` `DataSet to get at the data you need to get at it's underlying Table[0]

Comment: Why not look it up in [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.bindingsource%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and read through all the added Properties it gives you?

Comment: AutoGenerate columns is not required for a DGV generated from an Adapter.  I usually from an Adapter just fill a DataTable instead of a DataSet.  The DataAdapter only returns a single layer table an no need to create a DataSet and then remember to use the index of the table ds[Tables[0];

Comment: @jdweng you dont even need an adapter to fill a datatable; that can be also filled using `dbCommand.ExecuteReader()`:

Comment: The answer of your question is [Remarks](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.bindingsource(v=vs.110).aspx#Anchor_8) section of `BindingSource` class documentations.